# How to horizontally justified list-items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been all over stackoverflow looking for a solid solution for this; however, I'm coming up a short.  I believe my problem is just in my semantics.

http://jsfiddle.net/hzRAN/10/
here's some sample code.

*For best results: I would love for this script to **re-adjust** if there is a page width change.*

the real code is linked from this website
http://designobvio.us/DoUs/Blog.html
its a fluid layout which is why I need the horizontal list item to justify itself correctly.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can accomplish this is by setting the width of each list item or by using padding:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;   /* remove the indention */
  overflow: hidden;   /* to enclose the float children */
  }

li {
  width: 20%;  /* actually, use some slightly undersized value to supply a bit of slop */
  float: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use jQuery to achieve this, use the window.resize function, and then call that function on load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function() {
    // your code here:


    });    
    $(window).resize();
});​
```

I have managed to get a quick example running on jsfiddle (I forked yours) http://jsfiddle.net/rSeaE/1/ but its having trouble due to the width of the #daymenu I think.

Comment: hey man thanks for the support!  luckily I got this to work with css!